# pip не находит *.whl файл: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

При установке библиотек numpy и cipy через pip в командной строке отображаются следующие сообщения:

[image: результат неудачной установки numpy]

Как я понимаю, здесь рекомендуется обновить pip. Как можно это сделать? Или же проблема в чем то другом и её можно как то решить?

Comment: текст ошибки следует в виде текста копировать (чтобы другие люди могли этот вопрос найти). Если не умеете копировать, задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом (как скопировать текст в Windows консоль).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше, обновите (pip) pip install upgrade pip и смотрите чтоб пакеты совпадали с версиями Python 2 или Python 3. А whl файлы скачивать, то ненужное. Через терминал всё решается.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась копированием numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl в папку Scripts.

Comment: Не нужно руками whl-файлы куда то копировать и тем более не в специальные папки типа Scripts. Это обычный файл. Чтобы передать в качестве  аргумента в командной строке, просто укажите путь. Если вы скачали в папку `С:\Users\you\Downloads`, то из любой папки можете выполнить: `pip install С:\Users\you\Downloads\numpy*.whl` (если пишет что pip не найдена команда, тогда задайте вопрос специально об этом--решение: прописать Scripts папку в %PATH%).